# R: why does matching character "NULL" for function argument cause unexpected results?

Tags: r, function, arguments

The R code below produces unexpected results. (I put `NULL` in `b` just for testing. My interest is the character **"NULL"**)

```
f <- function(a, b = c('x', 'NULLL', NULL)) {
  print(a)
  b <- match.arg(b)
  print(class(b))
  print(b)
  print(b == 'NULL')
  print(b == "NULL")
  print(is.null(b))

}
f(2)
f(2, 'x')
f(2, 'NULL')
```

The results look like following. I assume for `f(2, 'NULL')`, there should be `'TRUE`' printed out, shouldn't it? Really strange to me! Any explanations? Thanks a lot!

```
R 3.2.3> f(2)
[1] 2
[1] "character"
[1] "x"
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
R 3.2.3> f(2, 'x')
[1] 2
[1] "character"
[1] "x"
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
R 3.2.3> f(2, 'NULL')
[1] 2
[1] "character"
[1] "NULLL"
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: It seems matching "NULL" is a bad practice in R. Is it?

Comment: Side note:  You might want to look at the result of `c('x', 'NULLL', NULL)`.  The third element will be removed.  Nulls in atomic vectors are removed.  If you need a true null element, use a list there.

Comment: Then shouldn't print(b == "NULL") produce TRUE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match.arg()` does **partial matching**: from `?match.arg`,

> Matching is done using ‘pmatch’, so ‘arg’ may be abbreviated.
>
> Value:
>    The unabbreviated version of the exact or unique partial match if there is one

so when the argument `b` is `'NULL'`, `match.arg(b)` gives the result `'NULLL'` (because the first four characters match).  The rest follows ...

Comment: Then shouldn't ``print(b == "NULL")`` produce ``TRUE``?

Comment: @AaronZeng - No, because `"NULLL" != "NULL"`

Comment: ohhhh, my bad! Thanks, just noticed I typed one more ``L``

Comment: OK, then voting to close as "off-topic because typo"